# Homebrewing self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: I just went through and fixed the problems that I knew how to fix with the listed questions.

Comment: @baka Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

[What is causing a bad flavor after cold conditioning?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6992/what-is-causing-a-bad-flavor-after-cold-conditioning)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm ok with this one, but I'm not unbiased, as I provided one of the answers.    The question could have had some more useful descriptors, but it was enough to derive the problem.

Comment: This question could be written better, it does not describe the issue with the beer. The comments from the community are good and draw out the issues. I like the answers

Answer (score 3):

[Ideas for rescuing an under-pitched and under-hopped batch](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7034/ideas-for-rescuing-an-under-pitched-and-under-hopped-batch)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Well formulated question, well thought out answers.

Answer (score 3):

[Why isn't my gravity increasing? Has fermentation stopped?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/why-isnt-my-gravity-increasing-has-fermentation-stopped)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Question seems ridiculous to experienced brewers, but underscores something that could be quite confusing to new brewers who don't have a grasp of the science behind brewing.   Answers and related comments are useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Premature Kegging - leave batch in keg or rack to carboy?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6995/premature-kegging-leave-batch-in-keg-or-rack-to-carboy)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, good answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Stainless Steel Scrubber in Boil Screen to strain hops?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7007/stainless-steel-scrubber-in-boil-screen-to-strain-hops)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Tone of the question is odd, but I don't have an expressable problem with it or the answers per se.

Answer (score 0):

[Priming a Tap-A-Draft system](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/priming-a-tap-a-draft-system)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is another with something odd that I can't really put my finger on.

Answer (score 0):

[How to lower Final Gravity?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/fg-for-high-alc-content)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question should be edited to remove all the abbreviations and grammar problems.   Both answers are useful.   sort of a toss-up.

Answer (score 0):

[Will the addition of cinnamon to apple cider cause additional fermentation?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/apple-cider-addition)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Something about this one "smells" odd, but I can't really put my finger on what it is.

Comment: I think this question is OK, except that it has a poor title.

Answer (score -2):

[Do yeast die after bottling?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7024/do-yeast-die-after-bottling)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking what the original poster is actually trying to figure out, which is derivable from comments.

Answer (score -3):

[Getting custom beer crates in the US?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/getting-custom-beer-crates-in-the-us)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think sourcing materials would be appropriate for the chat room, but it doesn't fit in with my perception of what the site-proper should be.